# can anybody suggest a package for neural ode for tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I tried this : https://github.com/titu1994/tfdiffeq,
but had an issue and cannot proceed further - https://github.com/titu1994/tfdiffeq/issues/10

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow Probability has differentiable ODE solvers [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/math/ode/Solver).

You will get used to TFP solvers soon because the interface is much similar to tfdiffeq.
(But it also has some issues and I'm having trouble too)